# Pin, Slot, and Spring Equilibrium

Tags: moments

I am checking to see if this is done correctly, the slot is a little confusing for me.

B is a pin in a slot, solve for the spring constant (k) so the 50 lb force applied does not move pin B

Solving for the moment about A I get

50lbs*2" - sin45(N)*3"

N = 47.1 lbs

Then solving for forces in the Y direction I get

k*.125" - sin45(N) ==> k = 33.2lbs/(.125") = 266 lbs/in

[image]

Comment: How is a 50# force horizontally affecting a vertically compressed spring?  Can you try to re-draw in 3-D for clarity?